# Generate a matrix(double) through colon operator in MATLAB and store it in cell

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, linspace

From the following code, I want to generate a matrix from the colon operator through a for-loop and have starting and ending values given in ends(20x2 double) where 1st and 2nd column of ends is the starting and ending values respectively.

```
for hh=1:length(ends)
xx{:,hh}=ends(hh,1)-1:ends(hh,2)+1;
end
```

and it is giving me the following error message

```
Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 0 results.

Error in new_one (line 11) 
xx{:,hh}=ends(hh,1)-1:ends(hh,2)+1;
```

Comment: What is the value of `ends(hh,:)` when you get the error? Please provide sample input.

Answer (score 2):

The error is likely due to an incorrect combination of `xx{:,hh}=...` with an incompatible initialization of `xx`, such as `xx={}`, which prevents `:` from evaluating to any row number. The following code should work:

```
% Simulated data
ends=randi(16,[20 2]);
ends=[min(ends,[],2) max(ends,[],2)];

% Create cell array
xx=cell([1 size(ends,1)]);
for hh=1:size(ends,1)
  xx{hh}=ends(hh,1)-1:ends(hh,2)+1;
end
```